# How to add where field <=, order by and limit to a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@news = Article.where(creation_date: $crdate).order(:created_at).limit(4)
```

I found the above code. How can I change the condition `creation_date = $cr_date` in the above query to `creation_date <= $cr_date`?

Pls help!

Comment: You'll find answers here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: check this - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#placeholder-conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
@news = Article.where("creation_date <= ?", $crdate).order(:created_at).limit(4)
```

If you want to sort articles in a descending order, you can do so by changing the syntax to

```
@news = Article.where("creation_date <= ?", $crdate).order("created_at DESC").limit(4)
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I mention descending in the order please?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the docs for future reference, but you can do so by doing `.order("created_at desc") `

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@news = Article.where("creation_date<=?",$crdate).order(:created_at).limit(4)
```